# How to assign a value to a variable in JQUERY

Tags: jquery, validation

```
if($('#error-email-id').val() === '' || 
  ($("#error-email-id").val()) === 'Please enter email ID' || 
  (!filter.test($("#error-email-id").val())) )

{
```

here I want that the the value in the field remains `"Please Enter email id"`. But When I enter wrong id say `"afafaf.com"` then after validating it remains `"afafaf.com"` But I want if it fails the validation it should be `"Please Enter email id"`

```
 return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the value using [**`.val(value)`**](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2) method

```
$("#error-email-id").val("Please enter email ID");
```

Answer (score 0):

Then just set it as value:

```
if( /* ... lots of conditions here ... */) {
   $("#error-email-id").val('Please enter email ID'); 
   return false;
}
```

See the documentation of [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Answer (score 0):

Assign it explicitly inside your validation

```
$("#error-email-id").val('Please enter email ID')
```